# Better Way to Define an Enum in Haskell

Tags: haskell, enums

I want a datatype to represent a finite set of integers that can be addressed by specific names. I figure the best way to do that is to use an Enum.

However, there is one small problem. The only way I know for defining an Enum is something like this:

```
data MyDataType = Foo | Bar | Baz

instance Enum MyDataType 
 toEnum 0 = Foo
 toEnum 1 = Bar
 toEnum 2 = Baz

 fromEnum Foo = 0
 fromEnum Bar = 1
 fromEnum Baz = 2
```

Note that I have to repeat the same pair two times - one time when defining an integer-to-enum mapping and the other time when defining an enum-to-integer mapping.

Is there a way to avoid this repetition?

Comment: Do you know about `deriving Enum` ? It is magical!

Comment: Ok, but it probably will not work if the values that are assigned to the names are not sequential, e.g. Foo should be 2, Bar should be 4, Baz should be 8, etc.

Comment: Aside from Augustss's suggestion, a method I've used is to derive Enum and place filler types in the gaps (when the gaps are small):  `data SomeEnum = ValueA | Reserved1 | Reserved2 | ValueB | Reserved3 | ValueC`

Comment: Something to note, though - long hand, as per the code in the question, is both efficient and clear. Sometimes scraping boilerplate isn't the best path.

Comment: If the values you want are in fact 2, 4, 8, 16, etc. it seems to me there might be another way. Like, use `deriving Enum`, but then write your own version of the `toEnum'` and `fromEnum'` which call `toEnum` and `fromEnum` and then do the 2^x conversion. Whether this is any better, I don't know.

Comment: If the values are not continuous, then I would not define an `Enum` instance, at all. If you need powers of two, maybe you want to use the `enumset` package for defining flag sets?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
instance Enum MyDataType where
    fromEnum = fromJust . flip lookup table
    toEnum = fromJust . flip lookup (map swap table)
table = [(Foo, 0), (Bar, 1), (Baz, 2)]
```

Comment: ...where `swap` is the obvious `swap (x,y) = (y,x)` (defined in `Data.Tuple` in the latest Haskell Platform)

Comment: I know I am not supposed to care, but will this be optimized into something efficient by ghc?

Comment: @Florian, probably not. It's possible to write similar things that probably will be.

Comment: will GHC at least realise to only generate the swapped table (`map swap table`) once?

Comment: Something to be aware of when you're using this to assign your own integer values in a custom `Enum` instance is that the default definitions of all the other methods of `Enum` in terms of `fromEnum` and `toEnum` make the assumption that they can use arithmetic on the integer codes to step between values. For example the [default definition of `succ`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Enum.html#succ) is just `succ = toEnum . (+ 1) . fromEnum`, which doesn't work if you're not using a continuous subset of `Int` as your codes. You need to define the other methods too

Answer (score 70):

```
data MyDataType = Foo | Bar | Baz deriving (Enum)
```

Comment: Good for sequential enum values (like in my example), but will it work if the values are not sequential (e.g. Foo should be 2, Bar should be 4, and so on?)

Comment: Not directly - but if you can write a bijective function `f` which turns the consecutive integers from 0..n into the integers you want, you can define a `newtype MyRealDataType = MyRealDataType MyDataType` and give it an `Enum` instance which "corrects" the values produced by the `Enum` instance of `MyDataType`. The disadvantage is you have to unwrap it when you want to pattern match directly on the names, etc.

Comment: Problem is, there is no specific law according to which the values change (they are not powers of 2, for example).

Answer (score 18):

The problem with the accepted solution is the compiler won't tell you when you are missing an enum in your table. The `deriving Enum` solution is great, but it won't work if you want to have an arbitrary mapping to numbers. Another answer suggests Generics or Template Haskell. This follows up on that by using `Data`.

```
{-# Language DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Data
data MyDataType = Foo | Bar | Baz deriving (Eq, Show, Data, Typeable)

toNumber enum = case enum of
   Foo -> 1
   Bar -> 2
   Baz -> 4
```

We will get compiler warning in the `toNumber` case mapping when a new constructor is added.

Now we just need the ability to turn that code into data so that the mapping can be automatically reversed. Here we generate the same `table` mentioned in the accepted solution.

```
table = map (\cData -> let c = (fromConstr cData :: MyDataType) in (c, toNumber c) )
      $ dataTypeConstrs $ dataTypeOf Foo
```

You can fill out an `Enum` class just the same as in the accepted answer. Unmentioned there is that you can also fill out the `Bounded` class.

Answer (score 4):

My examples here are using GHCI 8.4.4 with a prompt, `"λ: "`.

I think deriving from `Enum` makes the most sense here, as the most fundamental types in Haskell also derive from `Enum` (tuples, characters, integers, etc...), and it has [builtin methods](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum) of getting values into and from the enum.

First, create a data type deriving `Enum` (and `Show` so you can view the value in the REPL and `Eq` to enable `..` range completion):

```
λ: data MyDataType = Foo | Bar | Baz deriving (Enum, Show, Eq)
λ: [Foo ..]
[Foo,Bar,Baz]
```

Enums define a method, [`fromEnum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromEnum), which you can use to get the values as requested in the question (`0`, `1`, and `2`).

Usage:

```
λ: map fromEnum [Foo ..]
[0,1,2]
```

It is a simple matter to define a function giving an arbitrary value (such as powers of two using the integer power operator, `^`):

```
λ: value e = 2 ^ (fromEnum e)
```

Usage:

```
λ: map value [Foo ..]
[1,2,4]
```

Another answer says:

> The `deriving Enum` solution is great, but it won't work if you want to have an arbitrary mapping to numbers.

Well, let's see about that (use `:set +m` to enable multiline input in GHCI, if you haven't already):

```
arbitrary e = case e of
  Foo -> 10
  Bar -> 200
  Baz -> 3000
```

Usage:

```
λ: map arbitrary [Foo ..]
[10,200,3000]
```

We just demonstrated that it does indeed work, but I would prefer to calculate it from the `fromEnum` as we did with `value`, if we do not want values increasing by 1 from 0.

Answer (score 3):

Since you say the numbers are not generated by any regular law, you could use generic programming (e.g. with Scrap Your Boilerplate) or Template Haskell to implement a generic solution to this problem. I tend to prefer Template Haskell because it actually generates code and compiles it, so you get all the type-checking and optimisation benefits of GHC.

I wouldn't be surprised if someone had implemented this already. It should be trivial.

Comment: OK, I should have thought of augustss's solution. The only advantage of this one is that you don't need to list out all the constructor names twice.

Comment: And yours gets optimized.and checked properly.