# How to implement this functionality in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have defined a data type as follows in Haskell,

```
data Numbers = "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5"
```

I want to write a function which will give me the next number if given a number, except if I give it 4(I do not want it to give me 5 then).

```
next :: Numbers -> Numbers
next number = .....
```

I am a bit lost on how I can do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us what have you tried.

Comment: A few tips. Identifiers can't start with numbers in haskell so data  Numbers = 1  | 2... is not correct. You seen to have a type named Numbers but your function next operates on Number without an "s".

Comment: "*except if I give it 4*" - what do you want to happen then? Your function signature should express that, currently it says that it will give you a `Number` for *every* `Number` that you pass in.

Comment: I'm sorry. The numbers are strings, so I have made that correction in the question. As for what I am thinking of, i plan on explicitly doing "if number == "1" then "2" else if number == "2" then "3" ... and so on. It seems very orimitive to me however.

Comment: "I have defined a data type... `data Numbers = "1" | "2" | "3" | "4"`". No you haven't. Show us your *actual* code.

Comment: This is my code however. I am just experimenting with haskell by trying things to see how they work and see how much I have learnt so far. Do let me know if there is an issue in how I have defined my cutom data type if that is what you meant however.

Comment: @Obsidian_42 what is meant by "actual" code is the code which you have tried in GHCi, not on a piece of paper. then you'd get some error messages, which you should also always include in full with your questions. then your questions won't be getting downvoted, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [pattern matching syntax](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions).

If you want to go for a more advanced solution, look into [`deriving Enum`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6000511/1048572) and the [`succ` method](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:succ)